# How to join two total tables using sql?

Tags: sql, join, databricks-sql

For a university work we have two tables in sql:

table1:

```
         column_name1      number_P1
           PARIS             10
           LISBOA            20
           RIO               30
```

table2:

```
         column_name2      number_P2
           PARIS             100
           NEW YORK          300
```

I need to join the two tables by adding the total number of people in each city. So I tried to do:

```
SELECT table1.column_name1,
       number_P2 + number_P1 AS TOTAL       
       
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

However, if a city A appears in table 1 and does not appear in table 2 this would not work. The same would happen if a City B appears in table 2 and does not appear in table 1. How can I generalize these situations?

Desired output:

```
         column_name      number_P
           PARIS             110
           LISBOA            20
           RIO               30
           NEW YORK          300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try to use `UNION ALL` with `SUM` instead of `JOIN`

```
SELECT column_name, 
       SUM(number_P) number_P
FROM (
    SELECT column_name1 as column_name,number_P1 as number_P
    FROM table1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column_name2,number_P2
    FROM table2
) t1
GROUP BY column_name
```

Comment: I have one more question, how do I rename a specific city. For example, where is "RIO" I would like to change it to "RIO DE JANEIRO"

Comment: I think you can try to use `CASE WHEN` expression which can help us judgment value like `if...else`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this without a subquery.

```
SELECT IFNULL(table1.column_name1,table2.column_name2) AS ColumnName,
       (IFNULL(number_P2,0)+ IFNULL(number_P1,0)) AS TOTAL       
FROM table1
FULL JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name1 = table2.column_name2;
```

Output

| ColumnName | TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| PARIS | 110 |
| LISBOA | 20 |
| RIO | 30 |
| NEW YORK | 300 |

To replace 'RIO' with 'RIO DE JANEIRO'

```
SELECT CASE IFNULL(table1.column_name1,table2.column_name2) 
    WHEN 'RIO' THEN 'RIO DE JANEIRO' 
    ELSE IFNULL(table1.column_name1,table2.column_name2) END AS ColumnName,
    (IFNULL(number_P2,0)+ IFNULL(number_P1,0)) AS TOTAL       
FROM table1
FULL JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name1 = table2.column_name2;
```

Comment: I have one more question, how do I rename a specific city. For example, where is "RIO" I would like to change it to "RIO DE JANEIRO"

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: I using SQL Databricks

Comment: You can use `CASE` statement for this. E.g. `CASE column_name1 WHEN 'RIO' THEN 'RIO DE JANEIRO' ELSE column_name1 END AS column_name`.

Comment: Can you help me? How would you look at this query?
SELECT column_name, 
       SUM(number_P) number_P
FROM (
    SELECT column_name1 as column_name,number_P1 as number_P
    FROM table1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column_name2,number_P2
    FROM table2
) t1
GROUP BY column_name

Comment: In your outer query, apply `CASE` statement in `column_name` column. E.g. `SELECT CASE column_name WHEN 'RIO' THEN 'RIO DE JANEIRO' ELSE column_name END AS column_name, SUM(number_P) number_P FROM...`

Comment: You can also use `REPLACE` like this: `SELECT REPLACE(column_name, 'RIO','RIO DE JANEIRO') AS column_name, SUM(number_P) number_P FROM...`. **But this will also include cases where the value is already 'RIO DE JANEIRO'**.